# How to avoid 'else' in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Is there a better way to do this? A friend told me to avoid `else`, in order to keep the code clean, but i can't figure out another way to do this.

```
if listA[0] in listB:
    k = listA[0]
else:
    k = listB[1]
```

Comment: You could make it slightly shorter with `k = listA[0] if listA[0] in listB else listB[1]`, but that's a little harder to read.  This is perfectly acceptable code, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the if statement, you could do

```
k = listB[1]
```

That way there is no else. The entire block would look like this:

```
k = listB[1]
if listA[0] in listB:
    k = listA[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator assignment:

```
k = listA[0] if listA[0] in listB else listB[1]
```

https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-do-ternary-operator-assignment-python.cfm

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't argue about it being a "better" way to do it, but here's another way to avoid `else`:

```
def foo():
  #do stuff

  if listA[0] in listB:
    return listA[0]

  return listB[1]
```

Btw, I've been on several projects and they've had different style guides.